# Retrieving client name in IdentityServer4 and ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

The `dbo.Clients` table in the IdentityServer database contains both `ClientId` and `ClientName`, however requesting a client credentials token doesn't include the client name in the token.

Is there a way to either retrieve client information from IdentityServer given the client id, or request that the client name be added to the token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add them dynamically using a custom token request validator :

```
public class ClaimClientsUpdated : ICustomTokenRequestValidator
{
    public Task ValidateAsync(CustomTokenRequestValidationContext context)
    {
        context.Result.ValidatedRequest.Client.AlwaysSendClientClaims = true;
        context.Result.ValidatedRequest.ClientClaims.Add(new Claim("name", context.Result.ValidatedRequest.Client.ClientName));

       return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Register in DI :

```
services.AddTransient<ICustomTokenRequestValidator, ClaimClientsUpdated>();
```

It will add prefix "client_" to custom claims , so claim will be `"client_name": "value"` in access token .

Answer (score 1):

You can add information about the client in general by adding claims to the ClientClaims table. E.g. `Type = Name, Value = MyCustomName`

Which is added as claim (assuming prefix `client_`):

```
"client_Name": "MyCustomName"
```

This will allow you to add information about the client without having to add or change code.

The drawback for the client name is that you'll have to add a claim with redundant information, as Clients.ClientName is not the source. The advantage is that it's configuration only.

Comment: Thank you! This is a powerful general-purpose approach, but I think I'm edging towards @nan-yu's validator, just to avoid two sources of truth.

Comment: @nullPainter That's fine. I just wanted to mention this alternative so you are aware of it. On the other hand, you'll only have to set it once. It's not likely the value will ever change since it's used as a key.